# UNION statement to join two columns in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello I'm pretty new at SQL Server and I've got a problem on my home work that's killing me, this is my final problem on the home work and for some reason I'm struggling with this last question.

The question goes like this:

> Use the UNION operator to generate a result set consisting of three columns from the Orders table: 
>   ShipStatus  A calculated column that contains a value of SHIPPED or NOT SHIPPED
>   OrderID The OrderID column
>   OrderDate   The OrderDate column
>   If the order has a value in the ShipDate column, the ShipStatus column should contain a value of SHIPPED. Otherwise, it should contain a value of NOT SHIPPED.
>   Sort the final result set by OrderDate.

Here is what I've got so far but it just doesn't seem to work.

`SELECT OrderID,OrderDate
FROM Orders
UNION
SELECT ShipDate AS ShipStatus
FROM Orders
IF ShipDate IS NULL THEN ShipDate = 'Not Shipped'
ELSE
ShipDate = 'Shipped'`

I don't want the exact answer because I'd like to figure it out but a nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE---------

Hey guys thanks for the help!
With a combination of everyones help I figured it out.

Here was the code that ended up working.

`SELECT OrderID, OrderDate, 'SHIPPED' AS ShipStatus 
FROM Orders 
WHERE ShipDate IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT OrderID, OrderDate, 'NOT SHIPPED' AS ShipStatus
FROM Orders
WHERE ShipDate IS NULL;`

Answer (score 7):

You're struggling with the need for each query in the union to have the same number of columns. Here is a bit of SQL (MySQL syntax) that will help you get over that hurdle. Now that you made those corrections to my query, here's the solution to the ordering issue:

```
SELECT OrderID, OrderDate, ShippedStatus FROM
(
    SELECT OrderID, OrderDate, 'SHIPPED' as ShippedStatus
    FROM Orders 
    WHERE ShipDate IS NOT NULL
    UNION
    SELECT OrderID, OrderDate, 'NOT SHIPPED'
    FROM Orders
    WHERE ShipDate IS NULL
) AS myQuery ORDER BY OrderDate;
```

Comment: Well I modified it a little to look like this.

`SELECT ShipDate AS ShipStatus, OrderID, OrderDate 
FROM Orders 
WHERE ShipDate IS NOT NULL = 'Shipped'
UNION
SELECT ShipDate AS ShipStatus, OrderID, OrderDate
FROM Orders
WHERE ShipDate IS NULL = 'Not Shipped';`

What I'm needing is the Columns OrderID, OrderDate, then I need another column that says OrderStatus and if the value is a NULL then it should say NOT SHIPPED and if the value is not NULL then it needs to output as SHIPPED.

The way I'm getting the NULL or not Null values if from the ShipDate column

Comment: I finally figured it out.

This Code ended up outputting the result I was looking for.

`SELECT OrderID, OrderDate, 'SHIPPED' AS ShipStatus 
FROM Orders 
WHERE ShipDate IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT OrderID, OrderDate, 'NOT SHIPPED' AS ShipStatus
FROM Orders
WHERE ShipDate IS NULL;`

Answer (score 0):

FYI SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same number of columns. The columns must also have similar data types. Also, the columns in each SELECT statement must be in the same order.

So I guess u need something lyk this. But i dono what is the use of union in here!!

```
SELECT orderid, 
       orderdate,
       case 
          when shipdate IS NULL THEN shipdate = 'Not Shipped' 
          ELSE 'shipped' 
       END shipstatus 
FROM   orders 
ORDER BY orderdate
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no if in select statement. You can only use if in global statement. Like

```
if (condition)
begin

select statement ***

end
```

What you want to do is the where clause.

Union join two select for distinct value only. Which will work for shiped and not shiped value.

So you do the first table for Shiped, and then the second for Not Shiped, then combine those two table with union.